# Creating a insert trigger on oracle views

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on my project for simple forum. For storing the datas i've database schema as:

[image: Database design]

To view the questions posted by the users easier i've created a view as

```
create view users_questions as select qid,username,questions from userinfo natural
join posts natural join questions
```

I am trying to create a trigger on that view to insert the data actually inserted 
into the table questions and post. I have basic knowledge on creating the trigger 
for tables[Had knowledge of trigger to backup the table rows when deleted]. But confused in case of the views, weather the instead trigger can be used in case of views to insert the data's into other tables.

**Edited With My Try For Creating The Trigger**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON USERS_QUESTIONS 
BEGIN
    insert into questions values(new.qid,new.questions);  
END;
```

Not working shows error like:

> Error(4,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(4,46): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: What is your question here? If such triggers are possible? Yes, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i10900) suggests that.

Comment: How to get the values that a user is trying to insert?

Comment: Be warned, by using triggers, you are putting a rope around your neck. Oracle recommends NOT to implement business logic with triggers.

Comment: Sorry not concerned about the oracle issues, for understanding the trigger uses. But thanks for the kind info @Ychdziu. Will never use in real life projects.

Comment: Coding suggestions - don't use `NATURAL JOIN`, as it makes it very difficult to determine what the join conditions are. Always state the join conditions explicitly so that everyone can see them. And always include a field list on your `INSERT` statements - that way your `INSERT`s will either still work after the table is modified, or you'll be able to easily find the statements which need to be updated. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
insert into questions values(:new.qid, :new.questions);
```

Colons in front of `NEW`

Comment: Or else add `USING NEW AS NEW, OLD AS OLD` to the trigger definition.